# Repeating user input menu

Tags: python

Task question:

" add a repeating menu to the program to ask the user which piece of data they wish to
view after they have entered the numbers."

I have created a while loop which has successfully printed out the first part of the menu, the maximum value. however upon entering "2" after the loop for the minimum value, the number is not shown loops the menu string only

```
annoyinglist = []
count = 0

while True:
    a = input ("Enter a number: ")
    if a == "":
            break
    else:
        a = int (a)
        annoyinglist.append (a)
        count = count + 1



b = 1

while b == int(input("Which option would you like: \n 1 - The biggest number entered \n 2 - The smallest number entered \n 3 - Number of values entered \n 4 - Total of values entered \n 5 - Average (mean) of values entered \n 0 - Exit \n ")):
    if b == 1:
        print (max(annoyinglist))
    if b == 2:
        print (min(annoyinglist))
```

According to the task, the results should look like this:

> > >
> >     Enter a series of numbers:
>
> 5
>
> 3
>
> 7
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 8

>

Which option would you like:

1 - The biggest number entered

2 - The smallest number entered

3 - Number of values entered

4 - Total of the values entered

5 - Average (mean) of values entered

0 - Exit

> 5

Average (mean) of values entered: 5.333333333333333

Which option would you like:

1 - The biggest number entered

2 - The smallest number entered

3 - Number of values entered

4 - Total of the values entered

5 - Average (mean) of values entered

0 - Exit

> 3

Number of values entered: 6

Which option would you like:

1 - The biggest number entered

2 - The smallest number entered

3 - Number of values entered

4 - Total of the values entered

5 - Average (mean) of values entered

0 - Exit

> 0

Exit

Answer (score 0):

Just change your final `while` loop:

```
annoyinglist = []
count = 0

while True:
    a = input ("Enter a number: ")
    if a == "":
            break
    else:
        a = int (a)
        annoyinglist.append (a)
        count = count + 1


while True:
    b_str = input("Which option would you like: \n 1 - The biggest number entered \n 2 - The smallest number entered \n 3 - Number of values entered \n 4 - Total of values entered \n 5 - Average (mean) of values entered \n 0 - Exit \n ")

    b = int(b_str if b_str else 0) #so that an empty string stops the loop

    if b == 1:
        print (max(annoyinglist))
    elif b == 2:
        print (min(annoyinglist))
    else:
        break
```

Issue was: by starting with `b=1` and then asking for `2` you beak the `while` condition immediately!